# Pandas to_csv adds extra line terminator by default - winpython 3.8.5.0, Pandas 1.1.0. Is this expected behavior?

Tags: python, pandas

Just upgraded to WinPython 3.8.5 and now an extra line is added with the Pandas DataFrame to_csv() method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.to_csv('d://data//df.csv')

# gives

,A,B,C,D

0,2,3,0,1

1,0,1,2,0

2,0,4,2,0

3,0,0,3,2
```

Where as with the line_terminator explicitly referenced:

```
df.to_csv('d://data//test.csv',line_terminator='\n')

# gives the normal output expected
,A,B,C,D
0,2,3,0,1
1,0,1,2,0
2,0,4,2,0
3,0,0,3,2
4,4,4,0,4
```

Did upgrade to pandas 1.1.1 from 1.1.0 but had no effect and looks like non-expectant behaviour.

Comment: No extra spaces in my csv with your first code. I'm on Windows10, JupyterLab 2.2.6, pandas 1.1.1., python 3.8.5.

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney I get extra spaces in my csv with the first code. I'm on Windows10, JupyterLab 2.2.4, pandas 1.1.1., python 3.8.5, winPython3.8.5

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney in there a specific Python distribution you are using?

Comment: See the link to issue raised in winPython. https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/884#issuecomment-686481876. Overriding os.linesep = '\n' indicates that that is where the issue is.